# How to embed vertical slider to a grid

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, slider, silverlight-5.0

I am using c# to code and i have a parent grid called myGrid which contains childGrid and this childGrid contains various rows and i found that rows are crossing the border of myGrid (which is parent of childGrid).

I tried to something like :

`myGrid.Verticalslide = auto;` but here in silverlight we dont have this facility how to achieve the target of having vertical slider so that i will be able to see all my UI elements on sliding vertically .

**How to do this in silverlight?**

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, maybe if you share an example?

Comment: @ChrisW. please see the edit of questiojn

Comment: Are you meaning `myScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;`, `Grid` doesn't have a `ScrollViewer` built into the template, it sounds like you need to embed your Grid in one?

Comment: yes something like this. But i wanna have a scroll bar to this myGrid and it contains so many rows (which further contains UI elements). How to do that. Please explain below in detail so that it would be hepful for someelse in future and i would be able ot lark it as answer.

Comment: Sorry my xaml is much stronger than my c#, I'll try to give an example a little later when I have some free time.

Comment: @ChrisW. it sounds like you need to embed your Grid in one? Yes you are right. Could you please give me a basic ides . hOW TO do that. after i can do it myself.

Comment: example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146931/how-to-add-a-grid-inside-a-scroll-viewer-programmatically)